# Output dynamic PDF from html in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pdf

I want to create a simple endpoint where I return simple css+html as a viewable pdf. In Node.js

something like this:

```
response.headers('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

let output = '<h1>some html</h1>'

let bufferData = Buffer.from(output, 'utf8');

response.body = bufferData
```